# Matrix3x2 Transformation

Tags: math, matrix, directx, transform, direct2d

Is there a way to build 2D transformation matrix3x2 to apply the following formula to the point:
dx = (point.X - translationX)/PixelWidth;
dy = (translationY - pointY)/PixelHeight;

I have tried to multiply two matrices: 
Matrix3x2.translation(-translationX, -translationY) * Matrix3x2.scale(1/PixelWidth, -1/PixelHeight)

But it does not work correctly.

Comment: I don't see such `Matrix3x2.scale` method - both require center point in addition to scales  https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd372275(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @MBo, Actually I am using a ShapDX and here both methods exists. If center point is not defined M31 and M32 points remains zero. `public static void Scaling(float scale, out Matrix3x2 result)
        {
            result = Matrix3x2.Identity;
            result.M11 = result.M22 = scale;
        }` What center point should I use in my case?

Comment: Zero center point is OK.   Emm.. Why not scale(1/PixelWidth, -1/PixelHeight)?

Comment: Ah, I am sorry, just missed this in the question body, I'll fix. I am using Matrix3x2.scale(1/PixelWidth, -1/PixelHeight)

Comment: Instead of 2D lines (roads) I receive something like 3D sphere which consists of lines starting from its center (for instance, [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Zgzfu.png) ). I will add the real render screenshot soon. However if I transform each coordinate manually by the mentioned before formula - everything is fine.

Comment: All seems OK for me: http://oi67.tinypic.com/insdj4.jpg

Comment: @MBo,Thank you for help. Apparently it is a SharpDX bug.

Comment: Your formula looks right. Try doing multiplication via your own function.